# Running mqttjs examples with node.js

Tags: node.js, mqtt

I'm trying to start playing with node and mqtt and I found this really nice library for the MQTT protocol that integrates it to node.js. The library is simply called mqttjs: https://npmjs.org/package/mqttjs

I've walked through setting up node js according to this simple guide: http://shapeshed.com/setting-up-nodejs-and-npm-on-mac-osx/ and the server created and launched in that example works fine.

I installed the mqttjs library according to the instructions on the node website (`npm install mqttjs`).

In the docs for the mqttjs library they say there is a server example in "`examples/broadcast.js`". It seems this has been moved to "`examples/server/broadcast.js`". I'm having some issues running this example though, the server never starts and in the end throws an error. Here is the output from my terminal:

```
daniel$ pwd
/Users/daniel/test/node_modules/mqttjs/examples/server

daniel$ node broadcast.js 

/Users/daniel/test/node_modules/mqttjs/lib/parse.js:113
  packet.topic = topic_and_len[0];
                              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
    at Object.module.exports.publish (/Users/daniel/test/node_modules/mqttjs/lib/parse.js:113:31)
    at Connection.parse (/Users/daniel/test/node_modules/mqttjs/lib/connection.js:81:26)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:88:17)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:397:14)
```

I've tried reading the docs but they do not seem to be updated and I can find no reference on how to run the examples given with the library. If anyone has any experience in this, I'd be very greatful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to access the server through a web-interface. I have had this probem before :)

Run this command:

```
node orig.js
```

Then in another terminal window, run this command from the client folder:

```
node client_test.js
```

It should start pinging the server